# AWS Simulate principal policy Showing incorrect results

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Iam trying to run simulateprincipalpolicy through java SDK and getting incorrect results.

I have policy something like this and attached this policy to role 'Myrole':

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "id",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Java Code :

```
SimulatePrincipalPolicyRequest simulatePrincipalPolicyRequest = new SimulatePrincipalPolicyRequest()
simulatePrincipalPolicyRequest.setPolicySourceArn("arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Myrole");
simulatePrincipalPolicyRequest.withActionNames("ec2:DescribeTags");
```

Result:

```
{
EvalActionName: ec2:DescribeTags
EvalResourceName: *
EvalDecision: implicitDeny
MatchedStatements: []
MissingContextValues: []
OrganizationsDecisionDetail: {AllowedByOrganizations: false}
EvalDecisionDetails: {}
ResourceSpecificResults: []
}
```

The response is incorrect because when i try to perform that action Im able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar situation by calling `simulate-principal-policy` directly:

`AllowedByOrganizations: false` indicates there is an Organization SCP, an organisation-wide service control policy applied that somehow the simulator interprets as its denying access.

The issue in my case is that there are some of Org SCP that deny all kind of access to some regions, but not to others.

The simulator seems to be unable to discern a given region from others, or at least I did not find a way to overcome this problem.